# Google api - Different result get from api/browser

Tags: google-places-api

If I open this URL in browser

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=STUDIO+DAL+BON+SRL+ASOLO+FRAZ.+CASELLA&region=IT&key=api_key

I can see one result for query.

If I try to get same thing from code (with the same URL), I obtain ZERO RESULT...why?

```
WebClient wsClient = new WebClient();
Stream stream = wsClient.OpenRead(url);
reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string resultString = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Google maps API license key?

Comment: Invalid API key